# How to display parent/child relation with two table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two SQL table `UM_Module`, `UM_SubModule`

In the `UM_Module` table filed definition

- ModuleID
- Name
- MenuID

and `UM_SubModule` child table filed definition

- SubModuleID
- ModuleID
- Name
- SubMenuID

Below the data present in two table

```
SELECT ModuleID,Name FROM UM_Module
SELECT  SubModuleID,ModuleID,Name FROM UM_SubModule

ModuleID    Name
----------- --------------------------------------------------
8           Menu Master
9           General Master
10          Master
11          Clients
12          Event Type

(5 rows affected)

SubModuleID ModuleID    Name
----------- ----------- --------------------------------------------------
1           8           Menu
2           8           Child Menu
3           9           Role
4           8           Area Management
5           9           Permission
6           9           Role User
7           9           Permission
8           9           Parent-Child Permission
9           9           User Permission
10          9           Role Permission

(10 rows affected)
```

> Expected result

```
SubModuleID ModuleID   ParentName       ChildName
----------- ----------- --------------------------------------------------
NULL        8          Menu Master      NULL
1           8                           Menu
2           8                           Child Menu
4           8                           Area Management
NULL        9         General Master    NULL
3           9                           Role
5           9                           Permission
6           9                           Role User
7           9                           Permission
8           9                           Parent Child Permission
9           9                           User Permission
10          9                           Role Permission
```

Can some help me to prepare the above output query?

I'm preparing some query but not getting the exact result what I wanted.

```
SELECT cdo.SubModuleID,parent.ModuleID,parent.Name ParentName,
CONCAT(parent.Name, ' - ', cdo.Name) AS ChildName
FROM UM_SubModule AS cdo
JOIN UM_Module AS parent
ON (cdo.ModuleID = parent.ModuleID)

//Query output
SubModuleID ModuleID    ParentName       ChildName                              
----------- ----------- ---------------- ---------------------------------------
1           8           Menu Master      Menu Master - Menu
2           8           Menu Master      Menu Master - Child Menu
3           9           General Master   General Master - Role
4           8           Menu Master      Menu Master - Area Management
5           9           General Master   General Master - Permission
6           9           General Master   General Master - Role User
7           9           General Master   General Master - Permission
8           9           General Master   General Master - Parent Child Permission
9           9           General Master   General Master - User Permission
10          9           General Master   General Master - Role Permission
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `union all` as follows:

```
SELECT cdo.SubModuleID,
       parent.ModuleID, 
       null as ParentName,
       cdo.Name AS ChildName
  FROM UM_SubModule AS cdo
  JOIN UM_Module AS parent
    ON cdo.ModuleID = parent.ModuleID
Union all
Select null, 
       moduleid, 
       name, 
       null
  From UM_Module
Order by moduleid, SubModuleID
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the `UNION ALL` option [given](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65481522/14868997) by Popeye, you can also do this inside an `APPLY`. This avoids scanning the parent table twice:

```sql
SELECT v.*
  FROM UM_Module AS parent
  CROSS APPLY (

    SELECT parent.ModuleID, parent.Name, child.SubModuleID, ChildName = child.Name
      FROM UM_SubModule AS child
      WHERE child.ModuleID = parent.ModuleID

    UNION ALL

    SELECT parent.ModuleID, parent.Name, NULL, NULL
  ) v
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer I'm facing an error while executing the query `Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
The multi-part identifier "cdo.ModuleID" could not be bound.`

Comment: Sorry fixed that for you. Do you understand what it does?